# Find SQL table rows where there are multiple different values

Tags: sql

I want to be able to filter out groups where the values aren't the same. When doing the query:

```sql
SELECT 
    category.id  as category_id, 
    object.id    as object_id,
    object.value as value
FROM
    category,
    object
WHERE
    category.id = object.category
```

We get the following results:

```
 category_id | object_id | value
-------------+-----------+-------
       1     |     1     |     1
       1     |     2     |     2
       1     |     3     |     2
       2     |     4     |     3
       2     |     5     |     2
       3     |     6     |     1
       3     |     7     |     1
```

The goal: Update the query so that it yields:

```
 category_id 
-------------
       1     
       2
```

In other words, find the categories where the values are different from the others in that same category.

I have tried many different methods of joining, grouping and so on, to no avail.

I know it can be done with multiple queries and then filter with a little bit of logic, but this is not the goal.

Comment: See `group by .. having count`. What database implementation?

Comment: The `FROM` clause is missing from your query.

Comment: Show the query where you are grouping, and we tell you what you got wrong.

Comment: ```group by ... having count(distinct value)>1```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT o.category as category_id
FROM object o
GROUP BY o.category
HAVING MIN(o.value) <> MAX(o.value);
```

You have left the `FROM` clause out of your query.  But as written, you don't need a `JOIN` at all.  The `object` table is sufficient -- because you are only fetching the category id.

Comment: I missed the FROM clause, it's been added. Your query worked like a charm!